# PHP usar onclick para realizar função de outra página

Tags: php, onclick

Tenho o seguinte link em uma cabeçalho (header.php):

```
<a href="./index.php" id="btnMinhasReservas2" onclick="irParaMinhasReservas()" class="ph00_9"></a>
```

A ideia é, quando eu clicar nesse link, ir para a página index e executar uma função chamada `abreAba()`.
Terei que configurar algo no arquivo ***index.js***?

Comment: Se vc precisa utilizar uma função que não é da própria pagina, ou seja, ela passa a ser utilizada por mais de uma, não seria melhor criar um arquivo a parte?

Answer (score 1):

A resposta é um pouco gambi, mas pode te dar uma luz para melhorar.

Passa um parametro na url avisando o script para executar a função:

```
<a href="./index.php?acao=AbreAba" id="btnMinhasReservas2" onclick="irParaMinhasReservas()" class="ph00_9"></a>
```

No teu arquivo php tu pega essa ação e executa ela:

```html
<?php

if (isset($_GET['AbreAba']) && $_GET['AbreAba'] != '') {
  abreAba();
}
```

Essa não é uma das melhores maneiras para fazer, mas pode te dar uma luz para melhorar sua lógica ai nessa parte.

Comment: Eu coloquei assim pra testar:

    <a onclick="abreAba(2,logado)" id="btnMinhasReservas2" class="ph00_9"></a>

E aí funciona quando clico (apesar de o cursor não virar o cursor de clique), mas apenas se eu estiver na página index.php. Como posso fazer pra mostrar o cursor de clique e como posso fazer pra quando eu estiver em outra página PHP do meu site?